# How do you display hint circles in Android?

Tags: android, geometry, stock

I'm wondering how to display the "hint circles" (I don't know what they're really called, and I couldn't find it anywhere) when opening an app for the first time. I've seen this in many stock android apps, but not in many third party apps. Is there even a way to do this?

Thanks!

Here is a picture of what i mean. (The blue circle with the OK, not the white one)

[image: What i mean]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a library for that, check [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView)

Comment: Thanks, but is there any documentation on how to use it? For example, how to position it and change the lettering?

Comment: look through the sample app in that repo and it shows you how to use it and what the limitations are

Answer (score 1):

From what I have experienced with these, they seem to just be a form of a splash screen, or another image overlaying the actual app. Even if the stock apps don't handle it like that, couldn't you just have the app open up a new screen that contained a mostly transparent image except for where you want the ring or other hints. Then you can just at a button to that screen, so that after the user has read all of the hints, then they could close the screen.

I do not know how to totally do this, but since you said you couldn't find any documentation on it, I figured this could either give you a solution or point you in another direction to keep looking.

Comment: Thanks! If the other method doesn't work, i'll be sure to use this.

Comment: @ezcats no problem. If you do get it to work, let me know. I might want to try this in some future apps.